# Sequelize - Associating Table and Query Records

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have run into an issue where I am receiving an error `Unhandled rejection Error: description is not associated to images!` and I can't seem to figure out why I receive this error. I have a foreign key set up within my `images` table and thought I was using the methods for model associations labeled in the documentation. Ideally I want to be able to use the body field from my descriptions model when the images are queried.

Tables:

`images`

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pattern` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageUrl` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageSource` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `description_id` (`description_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `images_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`description_id`) REFERENCES `description` (`description_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

`description`

```
CREATE TABLE `description` (
  `description_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pattern` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`description_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here are my two models:

imagesModel.js

```
var Sequelize      = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize("db", "admin", "pwd", {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql'
});


var Images = sequelize.define('images', {
    pattern: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'pattern'
    },
    color: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'color'
    },
    imageUrl: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'imageUrl'
    },
    imageSource: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'imageSource'
    },
    description_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'description_id'
    }
},{
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
            Images.belongsTo(models.Description, {foreignKey: 'description_id'});
        }
    }
});

module.exports = Images;
```

descriptionModel.js

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'admin', 'pwd', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql'
});
var Images = require('./imagesModel');

var Description = sequelize.define('description', {
    color: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'color'
    },
    body: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'body'
    }
});

Description.hasMany(Images, {as: 'images'});

module.exports = Description;
```

Here is my route and query:

```
router.get('/:pattern/:color/result', function(req, res, image){

    console.log(req.params.color);
    console.log(req.params.pattern);

    Images.findAll({ 
        where: {
            pattern: req.params.pattern,
            color: req.params.color
        },
        include: [Description],
        attributes: ['id', 'pattern', 'color', 'imageUrl', 'imageSource', 'description_id']
    }).then(function(image){
        console.log(image.getDescription());
        //console.log(doc.descriptions_id);
        res.render('pages/result.hbs', {
            pattern : req.params.pattern,
            color : req.params.color,
            image : image
            })
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing and matching different model definition patterns.  The associate function of your Images model is probably never getting called which is resulting in the error.  Take a look at the project [sequelize / express-example](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example) and you'll notice in [models/index.js](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/index.js) that a helper file imports all of the models and then calls the associate method on each.  You appear to be trying to do something like this in the definition of Images.  However with the descriptionModel.js file, you also try to do a pattern which is found in a single file definition where all of the models are defined in the same file.  You can do either, but it is best to pick one pattern and stick with it.

Furthermore, to get the table structure you desire, you would want to declare that description_id is the primary key of the description table.

If you were to use the express-example pattern, you'd want to have the following file structure:

```
db
| -- index.js
| -- images.js
| -- description.js
```

Your images file would look like this:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

  var Images = sequelize.define('images', {
    pattern: DataTypes.STRING,
    color: DataTypes.STRING,
    imageUrl: DataTypes.STRING,
    imageSource: DataTypes.STRING,
    description_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(db) {
        Images.belongsTo(db.description, {foreignKey: 'description_id'});
      }
    }
  });

  return Images;
}
```

And your description file would look like this:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

  var Description = sequelize.define('description', {
    description_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    color: DataTypes.STRING,
    body: DataTypes.STRING
  });

  return Description;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and see where I messed up in trying to use two table associations, one in each model. I am instead applying your methodology to my models, but keeping my format. I removed `Description.hasMany(Images, {as: 'images'});
` and added the `description_id` field to this model. These appear to be the only two changes from your answer and I'm still receiving this error. Do I need to refresh or remove and re-upload my data to my database? Am I missing changes?

Comment: If you keep your format, the associate class method in imagesModel.js is still probably not getting called which is why you see that error.  You really should change your code and file structure to one of the two patterns I mentioned so your code is more readable.